# Bike Race question - Loser gets to "be the girl"

Tags: meaning, etymology, idioms, pejorative-language

I don't remember which movie it was in, but there were two men (filled with testosterone), and they had this bet that the loser would *be the girl*. It was never specified what *gets to be the girl* means. Is there a fixed meaning to it in English?

Comment: In gay male relationships, the partner who is the "bottom" (i.e., the one being penetrated during anal intercourse) is often derisively referred to as "the girl" in the relationship. Not knowing the context, I can't say whether this was the intended meaning, so I won't post it as a full answer, but it is one way that phrase can be interpreted.

Comment: Without the movie, it might be pure speculation on what is meant by that phrase. (Though there are several possible explanations - Roger's being the one that came to my mind also).

Comment: It's not an idiom, so there is no fixed meaning to the term. The answer is speculation only, ans as such, is opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

It amounts to derision, because the lowest form of life in the minds of little boys are little girls. My grandson, aged 9 next week is in the middle of it, and I don't think has invited a single girl to his birthday party.

But most well-adjusted males grow out of it by the time they are about 12. Others have it for life.

Comment: Male youth sports coaches will sometimes try to motivate their male players by deriding and calling them girls. It's quite politically incorrect (and will thus limit the coach's career) as well as being pretty inaccurate- if you've ever seen Canadian girls and women play hockey, it's more something to inspire awe and fear than something to disparage.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the OP misheard the line quoted from the movie. Instead, the most likely and most common phrase said in movies where there are two men and a woman involved is the following

**Loser gets the girl**

There are two interpretations for this line. The first being that the two bikers are making a bet, and the *loser* "wins" the girl. The girl in question, especially in comedies, is normally overweight,  unattractive, and/or extremely vapid. The *winner* of the bet gets to go out with the bestfriend of the former. And of course, she has all the typical characteristics of a beautiful desirable woman.

The second interpretation is also a clichè in American movies, where the protagonist is defined as being a *loser*; the man in question might be painfully shy, a nerd, a bit weird looking, an outsider, someone who is easily pushed around etc. At the end of the movie he and not his best friend or nemesis gets the girl.

[TV tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LoserGetsTheGirl) has this to say:

> **Loser Gets the Girl**
>   Two men get in a fight, or at least a highly charged physical
>   confrontation, over a woman they're both attracted to. One of them
>   wins, so naturally she spurns him and goes for the loser

[Ten films](http://www.scene-stealers.com/top-10s/top-10-hot-girl-nerdy-guy-movies/) where the *loser* gets the girl

> ... yet another movie where the schlub gets the hot girl has entered the
>   history books. It’s a trend that seems to be gaining steam lately, but
>   it certainly isn’t anything new.

Answer (score 0):

These could also be two men that enjoy... men.  And the loser of the race is going to be the girl.  The taker next time they have sex.

And I do have a lot of gay friends and (jokingly or not) I hear them say things like "next time you get to be the girl."

It is all about context though.